# .Net Compare Three Strings or Integers

Tags: .net, compare

Is there a way to compare three Strings or Integers in one time?
Something like this:

```
If 1=1=1 Then
```

or

```
If Strings.Compare("a","a","a") then
```

or

```
If "a" = "b" = "c" then
```

I don't want to use a & in the IF statement of two comparisons.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid `and`?

Answer (score 0):

If you put the items in a collection, you could use LINQ along the lines of

```
collection.Distinct().Count() == 1
```

to see if they match.

Alternatively, at the expense of seeming cheeky, `a == b and a == c` is the same as `!(a!=b or a!=c)` so you could use an `or` for three items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
int a = 1, b = 1, c = 1;

if(a == b ? a == c ? true : false : false)
{

}
```